# Why isnt my jquery .hide() working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple `jquery.hide()` function that is on all the divs with a class "groups".
But for some reason it doesn't work and I don't know why. I'm using rails 3 and have both put the jquery in the application.js file and the actual file 'edit' in script tag. Both don't work. can anyone see why?

Here's my .html.erb file

```
<h1 class="head">Edit information</h1>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username, :disabled => 'disabled' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :full_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :full_name%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

  <div class="groups">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :current_password %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :current_password %>

        <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
        <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
  </div>

  <% if current_user.has_role? :Admin %>
  <div class="field">
  <div style="width:150px"><legend >Group</legend>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
      </tr>
      <% for role in @roles %>
      <tr>
            <td><%= role.name %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %></td>
      <tr>
      <% end %>
      </table>
      </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= button_to 'Back', user_path(@user) %>
```

and my jquery which I have used in the js file and the top of the html.erb file

```
function (){
    $('.groups').hide();
};
```

its worth noting that ive tried:

```
$(document).ready (function (){
    $('.groups').hide();
});
```

aswell.

The application.js file gets loaded in the page as does jquery.
It's been a long day of code so I might be missing something obvious.

**Update**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PadOnRails | Edit user</title>
      <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="p64cHvc9nuBXOOHeV08Kg9FBsRxgQZlehw2xetHs57c="/>
      <!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="/stylesheets/custom.css?1313743921" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css?1313067331" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css?1312273016" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css?1313072205" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js?1312273015" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js?1312273015" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1312273015" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js?1312800139" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/datatable.js?1313666950" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.validations.js?1312877646" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/javascripts/error_messages.js?1313056625" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js?1312807797" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1313762558" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Container for all the content on the page -->
        <div class="container header">
            <header>
    <div id="top-menu">
        <div id="account">
        <ul>
        <li>Logged in as: <b>admin</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>

        <li>Current IP: <b>127.0.0.1</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="/users/6" class="round">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout" class="round">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="round">Home</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

            <div class=" maintitle">
                <div class="lefthead">
                 <a href="/"><img alt="Matflo" src="/images/logo.png?1312273015" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="righthead">
                PAD
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
                  <!-- Get contents from pages -->
                <div class="container main">
                <!-- Messages Blueprint => :error [red], :success [green], :info [blue] and :notice [yellow] -->
                <h1 class="head">Edit information</h1>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/6" class="edit_user" id="edit_user_6" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="p64cHvc9nuBXOOHeV08Kg9FBsRxgQZlehw2xetHs57c=" /></div>



  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_username">Username</label><br />

    <input disabled="disabled" id="user_username" name="user[username]" size="30" type="text" value="admin" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label for="user_full_name">Full name</label><br />
      <input id="user_full_name" name="user[full_name]" size="30" type="text" value="admin" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_email">Email</label><br />

    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" value="admin@dai.co.uk" />
  </div>

  <div class="groups">
        <label for="user_password">Password</label><br />
        <input id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" size="30" type="text" />

        <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br />
        <input id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" size="30" type="text" />

        <label for="user_current_password">Current password</label> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />

        <input id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" size="30" type="password" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <div style="width:150px"><legend >Group</legend>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td><input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Corporate</td>
            <td><input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>

      <tr>
      <tr>
            <td>ProjectManager</td>
            <td><input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" /></td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td><input checked="checked" id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="4" /></td>

      <tr>
      <tr>
            <td>TeamLeader</td>
            <td><input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="5" /></td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Engineer</td>
            <td><input id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="6" /></td>

      <tr>
      </table>
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="actions">
    <input id="user_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" />
</div>
</form><form method="post" action="/users/6"  class="button_to"><div><input type="submit" value="Back" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="p64cHvc9nuBXOOHeV08Kg9FBsRxgQZlehw2xetHs57c=" /></div></form>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Debug information outside page container- REMOVE WHEN FINISHED! -->
    </body>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="bottom-menu">
        <pre class='debug_dump'>--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
action: edit
id: &quot;6&quot;
controller: users
</pre>
    </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

Html straight out of the source as requested.

Comment: Are you including the jquery.js file _before_ the application.js include?

Comment: does it change the setting of the div with the class groups to anything...?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong here, try posting the HTML that is generated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/YKcHD/ works fine.

Comment: I honestly dont know why its not working. i even restarted my server.

Comment: This is likely to be some odd clash (which might be throwing an error, if we're lucky.) Hit it with the best browser debugger you've got (Firebug, Chrome inspector, IE "F12 Developer Tools".) Any console errors? Does it reach the code at all? You might also want to fix your more structural HTML errors (run it through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org)) and try temporarily removing all the scripts that aren't relevant to the problem and seeing if that solves it, then bringing them back in, one by one. Also, sanity-check: does `$(function(){alert('Hi!');});` do anything?

Comment: yep added a button on the screen and when clicked it said hi in an alert box... the js for that is in the application.js file... this is crazy

Comment: ok when i add jquery.js to the top of the html file it works.... yet it is also sitting right there in my application layout file. except its called jquery-1.6.2.min.... does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure prototype is not included, the '$' can be used by any library. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".groups").hide();
});
```

Extra: If you writing your script out of a HTML element, the correct is use double quote notation ("").

Comment: Better: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $(".groups").hide(); });`

Comment: nope neither works...its really strange but seems logically sound